# Can't login to my project using google or Yahoo OpenID

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, openid, janrain

Hi guys I've set up an openID login system - just like the one we have here on stackoverflow and on the backend I'm using JanRains libraries. It was working fine until all of a sudden - people can't login using a google or yahoo openid. ITs constantly failingt - instead however any other regular openid seems to work fine. WHats going on here - I tried to trace the error and for some reason its unable to retrieve the authentication Service - technically for those familiar with JanRain in the AUth/OpenID/Consumer file on line 339 or around that in the Auth_OpenID_Consumer :: begin function:

```
$endpoint = $disco->getNextService($this->discoverMethod,
                                           $this->consumer->fetcher);
```

The endpoint is returned null for anyone logging in with a google account - however other non google/non yahoo accounts log in.. whats going on here - my site is now live :( and I'm already regretting having implemented the openID thing....I first tried using Zends openID library - that failed big time and so I switched to JanRain - it worked for a while but now its failed me too....

Comment: Which version of the OpenID protocol does your copy of JanRain's lib support and what version do Yahoo and Google currently implement? Also, is there any error messages available?

Comment: uuuh.. nevermind...for some reason it happens mostly on my localhost when I try to test it from there..rarely online but I don't get any error messages at all.. just a response saying FAILED...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this is a symptom of your system's HTTPS-fetcher being busted, or improperly configured CA certs, since both Google and Yahoo are HTTPS-only IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo requires a valid domain name and not just an IP address.